# How to make a Sequential Http get calls from locust

Tags: locust

In Locust Load test Enviroment tasks are defined and are called randomly.
But if i want a task to be performed just after a specific task. Then how do i do  it?
for ex: after every 'X' url call i want 'Y' url to be called based on the response of 'X'.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, I found that it's better to model Locust tasks as completely independent of each other, and each of them covering a user scenario or behavior (eg. customer logs in, searches for a book and adds it to the cart). This is mostly because that's a closer simulation of the user's behavior.

Have you tried just having the multiple requests on the same task, and just if / else based on your responses? [This slide](https://speakerdeck.com/cgbystrom/load-testing-with-locust?slide=24) from Carl Byström's talk follows said approach.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to make a sequential gets or posts. When you define your task do something like this:

```
@task(10)
def my_task(l):
    l.client.get('/X')
    l.client.get('/Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an option to create a custom task set inherited from `TaskSequence` class.

Then you should add `seq_task` decorators to all task set methods to run its tasks sequentially.

https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#tasksequence-class